# ESS plot directly to an Emacs buffer?

Tags: ess, r

**Q:** how can I get ESS (R) to plot directly to an Emacs buffer?

When interacting with R through ESS, R defaults to spawning a separate graphics window outside of Emacs to draw its plots.  (One can, of course, choose other graphical devices, which is how we plot to PDF, etc.)  Two issues: first, the new window steals focus from Emacs, and second, it sure would be nice to keep everything nice and tidy within the Emacs ecosystem.

So: is there any way to plot "directly" (or even indirectly) to an Emacs buffer and, more importantly, do so without a lot of manual intervention by the user?

There had been some prior discussion in [this old Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053321/pop-up-windows-in-r-emacs), but the partial solutions proposed are not ideal.  They mostly involve changing the plotting device in R (say, to PNG), plotting to a temporary file, and then manually visiting that file in an Emacs buffer.  That all strikes me as very clunky, especially if the goal is to use the plot window/buffer interactively and draw many plots in a session (or add layers to them on the fly).

I'm speculating here, but it strikes me that, since both R and Emacs support SVG, that might be a useful format to use.  However, it's not clear to me if/how one could hook into the R process to communicate on the fly.  Is there a way to have R spit SVG code directly into an Emacs buffer, or would it need to go through the intermediary of a temporary file?  How could one convince Emacs to visit a new temporary file automagically when R creates it, or update such a plot buffer when the temporary file gets updated/overwritten by a new plot?

Comment: Emacs doesn't have to use a file and can instead use a string to insert an image into a buffer, see the docstring of `create-image`. I can't help you with actually making R and Emacs communicate with each other to achieve that though.

Comment: This has been discussed on the ESS mailing list: see https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2013-November/009559.html

Answer (score 6):

Not completly an answer to the question, but when one use R in org-mode's babel:

```
* My example
#+name: simple-org-example
#+begin_src R :session *my-R* :dir "." :results output graphics :file example.svg :width 18 :height 9
  plot(cyl~mpg,data=mtcars)
#+end_src
```

Doing a `C-c C-c` on this in org-mode will create a `*my-R*` buffer with an interacting ESS buffer, create the plot in the `example.svg` file and then you can click (or press enter) on the created link to the file, that will open it.

Org-mode is able to inline image, but it do it when toggling this functionality (with `M-x org-toggle-inline-images`) or on opening the file, but not on running a code in it.

So this is not a complete solution.

Comment: You can get the image to display automatically by setting `(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-display-inline-images)`, but this is (I think) still not really what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I just posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51236272/9210961) to [the old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053321/pop-up-windows-in-r-emacs) you are referring to in your question. As I wrote there, this may not work for you since it would be quite a dramatic change in your overall computer workflow.

But [exwm](https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm), by allowing any non-emacs window to be an emacs buffer, allows to have R plots in emacs buffers which are controlled by the usual emacs settings and keybindings.

Here is an example of what this looks like:

[image]

Comment: Could you share your config to achieve this? Looks very nice! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Maikol, I now use i3-wm, so I have long deleted my EXWM configuration. But this is simply 2 Emacs buffers side by side, one running an actual Emacs buffer and the other one running an X11 window for the plot (inside an EXWM Emacs buffer).

Comment: With EXWM, each X11 window becomes an Emacs buffer and you can organize them the way you would any other Emacs buffer (e.g. with `display-buffer-alist`)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, it is possible to write an elisp function to that will save the plot as a pdf and open in on a buffer next to the R process. See for example:

[image: plot buffer]

code:

```
(defvar rutils-show_plot_next_to_r_process t)

(defun add-pdf-to-rcode(rcomm fname)
  "add pdf(tmpfile) and dev.off() to R command"
  (let*  (
      (newc (concat "pdf('" fname "')\n" rcomm  "\n dev.off()"))
      )
    (eval newc)
      )
  )


(defun rutils-plot-region-or-paragraph()
  "execute region or paragraph and save tmp plot to pdf. Then open windows to show pdf"
  (interactive)
    (let*  (
      (fname (concat (make-temp-file "plot_") ".pdf"))
      )
      (progn
    (if (use-region-p)
        (ess-eval-linewise (add-pdf-to-rcode (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end)) fname))
      (progn (ess-eval-linewise (add-pdf-to-rcode (thing-at-point 'paragraph) fname)))
      )
        (ess-switch-to-end-of-ESS)
        )
    (if (window-in-direction 'right)
        (progn
          (select-window (window-in-direction 'right))
          (find-file fname)
          )
      (progn
        (split-window-right)
        (select-window (window-in-direction 'right))
        (find-file fname)
        )
        )
    )
    )
    )
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c g") 'rutils-plot-region-or-paragraph)
```

ref:
https://www.fredgruber.org/post/plot_buffer/